# Select all nodes by class excluding a specific container by parent id

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would i translate the following function into using .not (or not selector)?

```
   $(".CLASS").filter(function(i, e){
       return (e.parentNode.id != "ID");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('*:not(#ID) > .CLASS')
```

Comment: Can you explain this to me so i could understand it?

Comment: Okey. `*:not(#id)` is to select anything what doesn't have that ID. `>` is to select immediate child. `.CLASS` is selector as you used.